# HTML table inline css not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following line of code in my html page & table doesn't show up borders

```
 <table style="{border-color: black;padding-left:2px;border-style: solid;border: 5px;border-width: 2px; }">
```

Can you help me debug that.

Comment: remove brackets .. and for testing css chrome developers console can come in handy ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the unnecessary braces, the border CSS needs a little love. Try this instead:

```
<table style="padding-left:2px; border: 5px solid black;">
```

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax error. Remove `{` and `}`

```
<table style="border-color: black;padding-left:2px;border-style: solid;border: 5px;border-width: 2px;">
```

Also no need to write `border-color`, `border-style` and `border-width` separately. You can combine and simplify like below.

```
 border:2px solid black;
```

So you can update your code like this.

```
<table style="border:2px solid black; padding-left:2px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues involved:

- The curly braces `{` and `}` make the code invalid and cause it to be skipped. Remove them. Reference: [CSS Style Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/).
- The [shorthand `border` notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-shorthand-properties) always sets *all* border properties, using initial values as defaults. Thus, `border: 5px` sets `border-style` to `none` (and `border-color` to the value of the `color` property). The simplest fix is to remove that declaration; it seems to be meant to set border width, but used this way it has undesired side effects, and besides you are setting the width in later declaration (to a different value).
- Even when fixed, the code sets a border on the table as a whole only, not on its cells, and you might have meant to set borders on cells too. There is no way to do that in a `style` attribute of the `table` element; you need to set them in `style` attributes of cell elements or (better) in a `style` element or (even better) in a linked style sheet.

The minimally fixed code that deals with the first two issues is:

```
<table style="border-color: black;padding-left:2px;border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7xHtE/)

Your Code:

`<table id="table" style="border-color: black;padding-left:2px;border-style: solid;border: 5px solid black;">`